# Office 365 Skype/Lync: Support for stream multicast or mirroring?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, multicast, streaming, lync, skype-for-business-2016

Does Skype for Business / Lync when used via the hosted Office 365 service have the ability to do any stream multicasting or mirroring for group meetings?

Background:

I’m in a branch office with a few dozen users.  I’ve not done a full analysis, but when we all join a group meeting it *looks* like each of us has our own stream of data coming from the cloud.

Call, video, and screenshare quality are subpar. I suspect it’s due to our already overloaded internet link.  (We can’t sanely buy anything faster in our location.)

Is there any way to get a consolidated data stream going to/from the cloud? Or is that supposed to be working automatically?

(Installing some kind of “reflector” VM locally is fine, but obviously we still need to keep using the Office 365 service.)

I found something called the [Skype for Business Cloud Connector](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt605227.aspx), but this seems more about PBX connectivity rather than stream consolidation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, each client has its own stream. Keep in mind Office365 Skype for Business uses a server in the cloud not on premises.

Essentially what you are asking is can Skype for Business detect you are all in the same gateway and send all the data as one session. Ignoring that each session is separate no because Skype for Business does not to my knowledge consolidate traffic based on the gateway.

Your proposal of having a VM is essentially having an on premises server. If you want to do this you can build your own Skype for Business server and then use hosted Exchange.

Comment: Thanks.  Sounds there is no current solution without, as you say, building a local Skype for Business server for that part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Each multiparty conference is hosted and managed on the server side.  Peer-to-Peer calls/video in Skype for Business are used in 1:1 scenarios only.

There is no support for a "multicast" meeting, though you can edit CsConferencePolicy to restrict some bandwidth heavy features from a subset of users.

I would also recommend implementing Quality of Experience on the network.  There are some Skype client-side options for doing this, and your network equipment would need to support this.